# How do I import the javascript for a custom theme?

Tags: nativescript

In the official docs for NativeScript Core V2 theme (https://github.com/NativeScript/theme) it says:

> The core theme supports light and dark core styling and skins on top of that. In order to use the 2.0 beta theme, you will also need to include a small JS file in your project: `import "nativescript-theme-core";`

Exactly where am I supposed to include this import?

I'm using NativeScript with Angular.

Comment: If you are using {N} Core flavour, you may include it in your `app.js`.

Comment: I'm using the Angular version with typescript, if that's what core flavour means?

Comment: No, you are using Angular (flavour). You may do it in `main.ts` or in app module.